# rviz segmentation fault in electric, deb package

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am facing segmentation fault in running rviz (version 1.6.7-s1338538703) in ROS electric on Ubuntu. Installation is done using deb packages.

```
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization/rviz$ rosrun rviz rviz
[ INFO] [1342705533.959849989]: rviz revision number 1.6.7
[ INFO] [1342705533.959953268]: ogre_tools revision number 1.6.3
[ INFO] [1342705533.959972962]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.3 (Cthugha)
[ INFO] [1342705533.987722300]: Loading general config from [/home/dst/.rviz/config]
[ INFO] [1342705533.987899751]: Loading display config from [/home/dst/.rviz/display_config]
[ INFO] [1342705534.008773642]: RTT Preferred Mode is PBuffer.
[ INFO] [1342705534.142266475]: Texture for pass 0: creating with size 1 x 1
Segmentation fault
```

How I could avoid it? Is anyone facing this problem ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39217/rviz-segmentation-fault-in-electric,-deb-package/) by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on ROS Answers with karma: 660 on 2012-07-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you looked at [troubleshooting rviz](http://ros.org/wiki/rviz/Troubleshooting)? It is likely you just need to set OGRE_RTT_MODE

The relevant section says:

> Various OpenGL or Ogre things can go
> wrong during startup. One of them
> seems to relate to the
> render-to-texture system. Ogre
> supports 3 different modes, and rviz
> uses the "PBuffer" mode by default.
> Some users have reported some modes
> cause a segfault during startup, but
> it is not clear which should be used
> when.
>
> If you have a problem and want to try
> another "RTT mode", run rviz with the
> environment variable OGRE_RTT_MODE set
> to either "Copy", "PBuffer", or "FBO".
> For example:
>
> ```
> export OGRE_RTT_MODE=Copy
> ```

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-07-19**:
it worked! thanks for the link